# How do I change my Android Studio Gradle Module dependencies?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change my grade dependencies, from 26.1 to 28.00 my sdk version. I am doing this because in order to implement Google AdMob I have to have the same grade versions.

[image: A Picture of the dependencies I want to change]

Comment: why don't you specifically add `com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0`?  as well as any other non-28's

Comment: down-voted because the dependencies were posted as a screenshot. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Tried specifically adding the "com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0" it removed the red error but when I ran the app it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You have build.gradle at App level and build.gradle at module level. You have to change the second one.
Otherwise you can use the GUI in **Build --> Edit Build Types** and in the wizard instead of changing the Build Types you switch to the **Properties** tab.